I've got AttributeError: module 'telegram.ext.filters' has no attribute 'TEXT'
I'm making a telegram bot, that attempting to find other bots, channels, etc.
But i have got this error:
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "/data/data/com.termux/files/home/programs/antiscamer.py", line 29, in <module>

    main()

  File "/data/data/com.termux/files/home/programs/antiscamer.py", line 24, in main

    dispatcher.add_handler(CommandHandler(filters.TEXT & ~filters.command, find_bot))

                                          ^^^^^^^^^^^^

AttributeError: module 'telegram.ext.filters' has no attribute 'TEXT'

Its not a first error. With other errors i was fixing easily. But I have no idea how to fix this
Here's my code:
from telegram import Update

from telegram.ext import Updater, CommandHandler, MessageHandler, filters, CallbackContext

import requests

from telegram.ext import *

TOKEN = '7138699736:AAH3JUCxwy8jApWOqojGRZ7wFmC1CfVkG3A'





def start(update: Update, context: CallbackContext) -> None:

    update.message.reply_text(' Привет, это AnstiScammer_bot!\nВведите имя бота, которого нужно снести:')



def find_bot(update: Update, context: CallbackContext) -> None:

    bot_name = update.message.text

    response = requestsnget(f'https://api.telegram.org{TOKEN}/getChat?chat_id=@{bot_name}')

    bot_data = response.json()

    if bot_data.get('ok'):

        update.message.reply_text(f'Информация о боте:\n{bot_data["result"]}')

    else:

        update.message.reply_text(' К сожалению, не удалось найти бота.\nПроверьте правильность в названии бота или введите другое имя.')



def main() -> None:

    updater = Updater(TOKEN)

    dispatcher = updater.dispatcher

    dispatcher.add_handler(CommandHandlr('start', start))

    dispatcher.add_handler(CommandHandlr(filters.TEXT, filters.command, find_bot))

    updater.start_polling()

    updater.idle()



if __name__ == '__main__':

    main()

I was changing python-telegram-bot and telegram versions, and it's all not worked. I have no idea what need to do :(
